# Removing tags from SVG that are not supported by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, svg

Is there any tool/utility available that makes an SVG compatible with Android Studio usage. I already have tried using

1. Vector Asset studio by Android Studio
2. svg2android
3. svg2vector

but these are not working. I get following errors when I try to add SVG as vector asset in Android Studio project

1. ERROR @ line 26:  is not supported
2. ERROR @ line 27:  is not supported
3. ERRR @ line 28:  is not supported
4. ERROR @ line 29:  is not supported
5. ERROR @ line 30:  is not supported
6. ERROR @ line 31:  is not supported
7. ERROR @ line 32:  is not supported
8. ERROR @ line 33:  is not supported
9. ERROR @ line 34:  is not supported

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Usually, the image needs to be redesigned. You can look at lines 26-34 of the SVG to see what specifically the tool is complaining about.

Comment: You probably need to simplify your SVG - see [vector asset studio: restrictions for SVG files](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg-support) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to manually remove the problematic tags.